# Inversion property of full adder

Tags: adder

The given inverting property states that the FA stays the same if I invert all the inputs and outputs.

[image]

Using this idea we modify the ripple carry adder into the below form, but why can it be translated as below? Clearly there are many inversions missing, as highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Comment: Even cells are "non inverted" except the carry out. Odd cells are "inverted" except carry in. They are mixing the two, not showing a configuration with all "inverted" adders.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this was asked 9 months ago, not sure if you still need this answer. The first part of your question only shows an example of an equivalent transform, but we can extend that as follows:
[image: Equivalent transforms of Full]

We can see that from the truth table, I entered some values for testing, and eventually we get the same sum results.
The truth table basically computes Sum = A+B with some carry inputs, and carry outputs are shown as well (cout and complementary cout).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mistake.
An all-inverted input FA outputs the inverted signals.
It does not output the same signals as a non-inverted inputs FA.